# Need assistance with confusing powershell issue

Tags: powershell, outlook

I wrote a powershell script for use at my company. For whatever reason the part of the script that is supposed to remove all .ost files at the location specified only works some times. the Path for the ost does not change. Anyone have any idea's why this would be?

```
Stop-process -Name OUTLOOK -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-process -Name communicator -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-process -Name lync -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-Process -Name UcMapi -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-Process -Name skypehost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force
Stop-Process -Name searchprotocalhost -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force

$OstPath = "c:\users\$([environment]::username)"+ "\AppData" + "\local" + "\Microsoft" + "\Outlook" 
$ost = get-ChildItem $OstPath | where { $_.Extension -eq ".ost"}  
$ost | remove-Item -WhatIf

Start-Process Outlook
```

Comment: Is it because you misspelled `searchprotocolhost` ? Because you use `-WhatIf` and that means nothing is removed? Because some of your computers aren't storing user files in `c:\users`, e.g. they're not localised in English? Because another program might be using it, e.g. Mitel phone system PIM does.

Comment: corrected but it still is having the issue.

Comment: this is resolved now. I removed the -whatif and added -force and it clears it every time. my bad for not trying this ahead of time. Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

you will want to change you code to something similar to the below. I tested the below in my test environment and it worked without issues.

```
$OSTPath = Get-Item -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\*" -Filter '*.ost'

If ($OSTPath)

    {
        Write-Output "OST File Found, Deleting File...."
            Remove-Item -Path $OSTPath -Force
    }

ELSE

    {
        Write-Output "No OST Exists. No Action Taken."
    }
```

Since solution wasn't posted, thought I would add a solution for anyone that might come across this question.

Comment: This is a better method for getting the path that is more readable.